# How to make pycharm use a different cuda toolkit

Tags: python, pycharm, mxnet

I want to run an [MXNet module](https://github.com/msracver/Flow-Guided-Feature-Aggregation) in GPU.

I have a system which has Ubuntu 18.04 along Cuda 10.0 installed. Apparently this is not covered yet by MXNet binary files so I was focusing on [installing 2 cuda versions](https://medium.com/@zhanwenchen/install-cuda-9-2-and-cudnn-7-1-for-tensorflow-pytorch-gpu-on-ubuntu-16-04-1822ab4b2421) in my pc (see also [here](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Install-CUDA-10-together-with-9-2-on-Ubuntu-18-04-with-support-for-NVIDIA-20XX-Turing-GPUs-1236/)).

Anyway I now have 2 cuda toolkits in my pc in different folders. I need a way to direct my system to use Cuda 9.2 when run from PyCharm. The funny thing is that from a typical console I can run it just fine (at least the MXNet loading part that is of course).

In the module I want to run the program is stuck in:

```
import mxnet as mx
```

which leads to `base.py` in MXNet:

```
def _load_lib():
    """Load library by searching possible path."""
    lib_path = libinfo.find_lib_path()
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)  # <- This is where is throws the error.
    # DMatrix functions
    lib.MXGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    return lib
```

the strange thing is that `lib_path[0]` just points to the location of `libmxnet.so` (which is correct by the way) and suddenly it throws an error:

> OSError: libcudart.so.9.2: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Even if I follow the error trace the last command is this:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

with `self._name` being the same location of `libmxnet.so`.

I have tried to make it work by changing the system variable with

```
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64"
```

as the second line of the module (the 1st is of course `import os`!) but this does not seem to work. Apparently it's taken into consideration.

So, how can I bypass this? 
Any solution would be acceptable being on the MXNet side or pyCharm side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to make this available to anyone facing the same problem I will post my solution.

I managed to make it work by defining the environmental variable inside pycharm from the run configuration menu (the one that it's available from *Run->Run...* or *Alt+Shift+F10*) and defining it there as environmental variable.

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-9.2/lib64

I am not sure why for that case pycharm is working fine while when the same variable is defined inside the code it does not though (any explanation welcome).